# how to check if token was expired in models?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to expire tokens from forgot password requests, but `token` from PasswordReset becomes NULL after the user updates their password, however, I was thinking on some kind of solution, but I want to expire the token usage after 1 minute or max 5 minutes to meet security requirements, but I also got `created_at` . how can I set up an is_expire function to invalid the token?

```
if self.token == None:
  return False
do_expire
```

models.py

```
class PasswordReset(models.Model):
    email = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    token = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: Why are you not using Django's built-in [**PasswordResetView**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.PasswordResetView)

Comment: I dont know why , but is there a way to implement expired tokens?

Comment: why you should reinvent the wheel? Just use it :)

Comment: I am new in Django, and I didn't find any example how to implement the built in system with ajax